# Post value through load Jquery function that not visible in source?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

What i want to do is I want to load a page in the div

```
   $('div[id=main]').load('logo.php?id=<?php echo($id); ?>');
```

but user can open this page by typing in the URL /logo.php?id=123

```
   $('div[id=main]').load('logo.php',{ '12secret2': "hack"});
```

finding the code to hide the passing value by POST,that is not visible in the user source code and am able to redirect if it's not passed

```
    $('div[id=main]').load('logo.php',{ '12secret2': "hack"});
```

is visible am not able to hide the passing value

Comment: you won't be able to hide the value from the user as he can use any browser developer tool to see the requests.... from a third party you can use https to secure the values

Comment: @ArunPJohny can there be any way i can restrict user to open logo.php page please help Sir!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your conducting client server communication the traffic is always visible to the client side, no matter what you do. if you want security then you are to encode your client communication portion in some form of a binary code and then encrypt it some how. Which is still possible to be reversed.

Having said all that

> you should use session to maintain the data you don't want the client
>   to see

Comment: can there be any way i can restrict user to open logo.php page please help Sir!!

Comment: you should use session to maintain the data you don't want the client to see